# Get cURL response body in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, curl, database-migration

I'm working on a db migration where I need to upload images in the old db to Filepicker using cURL within the Rails console. I've got a command that works, and all I need from here is to grab the Filepicker URL from the response. However, setting the response as below just returns `true`.

So this will upload a file to Filepicker as desired:

`res = system("curl -X POST -F fileUpload=@oldimages/oldimage#{id}.jpg https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3\?key\=OURAPIKEY")`

Giving this output:

`{"url": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/THEURL", "size": 207610, "type": "image/jpeg", "filename": "oldimage1.jpg"} => true`

The problem is I can't assign the URL - the `res` variable only stores `true`.

So, in a nutshell, how to I get access to the rest of this data to assign it to an instance in the new db?

Comment: do you have to use curl here? Seems like `Net::HTTP` would be better to use.

Comment: Agree it should be, and that was our first approach; however, we're getting all sorts of errors based on discrepancies in the files' encoding. This way allows us to use the raw image data stored locally without any additional conversion -- by all means, if you think up an alternative, let me know! Thanks @Anthony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need run curl you can do this

```
 body=`curl -X POST -F fileUpload=@oldimages/oldimage#{id}.jpg https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3\?key\=OURAPIKEY`
```

or

```
body = %x(curl -X POST -F fileUpload=@oldimages/oldimage#{id}.jpg https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3\?key\=OURAPIKEY)
```

or

```
IO.popen("curl -X POST -F fileUpload=@oldimages/oldimage#{id}.jpg https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3\?key\=OURAPIKEY").read
```

But If I were you, I would try to use net:http or another ruby http client as typhoeus or restclient

Comment: Thanks @Horacio, that works a treat! I would 100% prefer to be handling this in another manner but we've had a tonne of unforeseen issues that have forced us down this route. That's solved it though, big thanks!